# NVCC behaviour for .cpp and .cu files

Tags: cuda

Consider two files:

1. test.cpp : contains an unused function `f1()`
2. test.cu: contains the same unused function `f1()`

These files are complied using NVCC and gives  two exe (1.EXE, 2.EXE).
Note that one is .cpp and another is .cu

During profiling, 1.exe does not show the unused function f1, But during profiling, 2.exe  shows the unused function f1.

Why? Why does NVCC behaves differently for .cu and .cpp files?

**UPDATE:**

My confusion boils down to:
Can I automatically inline the unused functions in .cu files, may be using some compiler option?

Comment: What are you using to profile the running code? Do you have access to a coverage tool? Can you confirm that the function is actually being called?

Comment: @taonmies using VTUNE for profiling.

Comment: How can you inline an unused function? That makes no sense, if it's unused then into what would you inline it?

Answer (score 1):

NVCC compiles .cu files itself and passes the .c and .cpp files to system's CC and CXX. Acknowledge that two different compilers may generate codes with minor differences.

Comment: Can I automatically inline the unused functions in .cu files, may be using some compiler option?

Comment: Optimization options (e.g. -O1 and O2) remove unreachable codes inside the kernel. But I don't think these options exclude unused function too. Please add your latest comment to the body of question to get its answer from others.

Answer (score 1):

First, is the function is a cuda function or cpp function? What is the OS you are using?

I have tried a couple of things and found this.

If it is a cpp function, both nvcc (.cu) and gcc (.cpp) compiles and run the code normally.
and, if you are using Ubuntu, it shows that the function is unused. (both .cu and .cpp). If you are using VS10, it wont show any warning.

If it is a cuda function, nvcc works fine. But, the .cpp file doesnt compile in both VS10 and Ubuntu. Even though you include the libraries.

Need to be more specific on the function and the OS.